# How to make remote links to update info without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a problem .. There are 2 links that need to update the information on the page without updating it. I'm not good at JavaScript and tried many solutions, but it does not work ..
In general, I have a button "Add item to cart" and toolbar displayed on top that shows number of items in the cart and the total value.
Parametes from cart are stored in session[:cart], like 
cart={product_id => quantity, product_id => quantity}.

When i click "Add item to cart" i need to update information on upper toolbar without updating page.
I have something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Add to cart', "/cart/#{product.id}", type: "submit",
                      class: "single_add_to_cart_button button alt", remote: true %>

$('.single_add_to_cart_button').bind('ajax:complete', function() {
                    $('#frontend-toolbar').text("<%= cart_info_quantity %>");
                });
```

But it doesn't work..

At the same time i have modal window that show products from cart and 'Remove' button, that removes one item.

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', "/cart/remove/#{product.id}", class: 'link-delete', remote: true %>
```

I have tried this function:

```
 $('.link-delete').bind('ajax:complete', function() {
                    document.getElementById("productt").style.display = 'none';
                });
```

But it doesn't update info in my cart, so i should reload page..

cart_info_quantity method:

```
def cart_info_quantity
if session[:cart]
  @quantity = 0
  @cart = session[:cart]
  @cart.each do |id, quantity|
    @quantity += quantity
  end
  return @quantity
else
  return 0
end
```

The same method for total price:

```
def cart_info_total
if session[:cart]
  @total = 0
  @cart = session[:cart]
  @cart.each do |id, quantity|
    @total += quantity * Product.find_by_id(id).price
  end
  return @total
else
  return 0
end
```

And method for all products from cart to display them in modal window:

```
def cart_products
if session[:cart]
  products = Hash.new
  @cart = session[:cart]
  @cart.each do |id, quantity|
    products[Product.find_by_id(id)] = quantity
  end
  return products
else
  return nil
end
```

Help me please, because I cant make it for a long time..

Comment: "There are 2 links that need to update the information on the page without updating it."    what do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean, I need to update the information on the page without refreshing the page. Sorry for my english.